# Accept only integer as an answer but also don't accept negative numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to ask the user a question and the input can only be a positive number. If the user tries to enter a word or a negative number ask him the question again. I tried putting an if loop but it didn't work.. The problem is that it accepts negative numbers.

```
int age;
            Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value must be of integer type");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age));
```

Comment: check that number should be greater than 0

Comment: A while condition can have multiple parts, so you could always do `while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age) && age < 1)` assuming you dont want to have anyone at age 0

Comment: `while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age) && age < 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing a condition in your while:

```
... } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age) || age < 0);
```

Comment: I'd also suggest the OP to use a while loop instead of do while as the latter will always print "The value must be of integer type" before the user has entered anything.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For your while loop, simply add an extra condition and use the or operator.

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age) || age < 0); //while not an integer or while the number is less than zero
{ 
  Console.WriteLine("The value must a positive integer");
}
```

Also, I would not use a do while loop, as the do part of your loop will always be executed before the while condition is checked. The way you have it written now, it will tell the user they have to use an integer type even if they do enter a valid integer.